# firestore - query for root entities

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, datastore

I have a collection that has a kind that also appears in some other sub collections.  I want to read all items in the root collection, currently I am doing

```
query = datastore_client.query(kind=USER_KIND)
results = list(query.fetch())
employees_dict = {}
for u in results:
    if not u.key.parent:
        employees_dict[u.key.name] = u
return employees_dict
```

Is it possible to limit the result to only contain root entries in the query instead of code?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer here was pretty simple.

I was using the google.datastore api and not the firebase api.

Changing to the official firebase python api solved it.  Had to do some minor changes since the apis had slight differences.